# Why do I get less securities than request in RefData?

Tags: blpapi

I am requesting RefData from Bloomberg API via c#.

I create a list of 912 securities.

But I get the final "RESPONSE" message after only 92.

Why might that be?

Comment: Maybe because the data you requested is not available for the other securities? Without more information it's hard to say...

Answer (score 0):

Bloomberg will split up responses for large requests so that each PARTIAL_RESPONSE event will contain data for multiple securities. Currently, it looks like each event will contain data for up to 10 securities, but I would not rely on that number staying the same as I seem to remember a few years ago it was 8.